# How to display object values on a webpage

Tags: html, web

I am trying to get user's input from multiple fields.
So here's my javascript to get the value from the html contents::

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('button');
var inp = document.getElementById('myInput');
var inpw = document.getElementById('myPW');
```

And here where I would like to display the inputs:

```
<h2>Data</h2>
<p id="val"></p>
```

What I've done is:

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const object1 = {
        un: inp,
        pw: inpw
    };

    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = Object.values(object1);
});
```

But the result is:

```
[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Comment: You probably want to get the `.value`s of the objects.

Comment: Use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: I dont know how. would you please give me an example? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figure it out:

```
const object1 = {
        un: inp.value,
        pw: inpw.value
    };
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(object1);

    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = myJSON;
```

Output:
{"un":"erin","pw":"pdds"}

Comment: [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is more effective and quick than the [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). The documentation link I gave you had examples, so there was no point in giving you one. I am glad you have figured it out.